# Rails database tables setup

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a `judo/bjj` site that allows users to create an account and keep track of their `judo/bjj` competitions, rank, competition results, etc.  The users can also join clubs from the site as well.

The problem I'm having is that if I am in judo, I want to be able to add all my judo info to a table, soI can add my current but when I get promoted I want to add that rank too.  The same for bjj.  I also want to have results for each tournament I fight in.  That part doesn't seem as difficult, but I can't figure out the best way to setup the tables for rank. If I do judo, I want to indicate that on my profile page and what year I started judo and my current rank, and the date I received it.

I hope that makes sense.  I just need guidance in tables and any thoughts on making this work.

Comment: Do you want to show all ranks a user has had.  So like, for example, in 2017 they were white belt, in June of 2018 they moved up to yellow (I don't know these orders, just making it up)?  Either way I think you need a table called `Rank` or something, that has a `user_id` and `club_id` and then the `rank` which is the color or name or whatever.

Comment: Ideally, yeah, but what about the other stuff like year started and the style judo/bjj?

Comment: Well the style would be related to the club wouldn't it?  You would need a few tables to support all this.  I do not think it would work well to put all this data in one table.  Perhaps there is an `Enrollment` table that contains `user_id` and `club_id` and then date of enrollment.  If you do not need to show all ranks earned you could include `current_rank` on there as well.  Not sure about the table name exactly but you are the only one who knows this app so you would have to write those out.

Comment: Not necessarily. I can be a member of may clubs.  LIke on facebook, my club has a page but I know a lot of athletes and  coaches so I'm a member of multiple club pages.  I just can't figure out how to do the tables.  In one I was working on before I have the ranks hard coded into a rank table  but it never realy worked the way I wanted it to.   Somy thought is to have a rank table where it would have id user_id, rank, date_of rank et, and somewhere I need to have year started and then I have to figure out how to pull date from all those tables into the users model.

Comment: Right so a club is one entity.  A users enrollment in it is another entitiy.  Thier ranks would probably be another as well.  So you have `users` and `clubs` and users have `enrollments` which `belong to` both users and to clubs.  They also have `ranks` which `belong_to` a user and a club.

Comment: The club isn't anissue.  I have the users clubs linked, but I use can have ran iregardless of the club.  I have Users, users, styles and userStyles.  In styles I have judo and bjj.  I have it setupso I can add a userstyle for judo and one for bjj if I do both.  If I add judo,  to userstyles can I have a year_started field in that userstules table, or should I put that somewhere else.  Ihave the same issue with rank,  If I create a userRanks table, can I store teh rank date in that table? And if so can I access that with user.ranks.rank or something liek that?